# Karate websocket send request body replace token failed

Tags: karate

I am using karate to test websocket, this worked:

```
Background:
    * def token = TOKEN
    * def handler = function(msg){ return msg.startsWith('a[')}
    * def socket = karate.webSocket(WS_HOST + 'socket/761/f4t0so3p/websocket', handler)

  Scenario:  Demo Real
  checking dcube-dev
    * socket.send('{"type":"1ffe4b5d___AC_GET_MY_AVAILABLE_TASKS___N","token": "myhardcodedtoken","content":{"msg":null,"counter_api_enabled":false}}')
```

You can see here, I am hard coding the token inside the request body, not good, so I tried to move it out and use environment token instead as below:

```
 Background:
    * def token = TOKEN
    * def handler = function(msg){ return msg.startsWith('a[')}
    * def socket = karate.webSocket(WS_HOST + 'socket/761/f4t0so3p/websocket', handler)

  Scenario:  Demo Real
  checking dcube-dev
    * def body = {"type": "1ffe4b5d___AC_GET_MY_AVAILABLE_TASKS___N", "token": '#(token)', "content":  {"msg":null,"counter_api_enabled":false} }
    * print "Body:", body
    * socket.send( '#(body)')
```

But this is always wrong, seemed the msg never sent out . Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you need to make this one change:

```
* socket.send(body)
```

Think of the round brackets as being JS - not standard Karate expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#enclosed-javascript

Also note, for strings (instead of JSON) you can use `replace`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace

```
* def text = 'hello <foo> world'
* replace text.foo = 'bar'
* match text == 'hello bar world'
```